# Imgcodecs.imread() java opencv for windows

Tags: java, windows, opencv

### Hello I am unable to read image on opencv because of file path.

I used a FileChooser (with selection of only image files), then it gave me a file, I tried to read image file by getting file path but it does not work. When I tried relative path, it works. Here is me code, i need some helpenter code here

```
     BufferedImage bufferImage=ImageIO.read(file);
     imageRequette=Imgcodecs.imread(file.getPath(),0);
```

Comment: You can use 'file.getAbsolutePath()' and try again.

Comment: It does not work

Comment: What is the exception message, or how do you know it doesn't work, can you post more code you used, or say more details?

Comment: When i print the size of imageRequette, i have 0x0

Comment: Can you show the code how did you done it? Or you can print the file path and see if it is OK. System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());